# jQuery Validation plugin already part of jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

My jquery:

```
$("#sample_form").validate({
    rules: {
        name: "required"
    },
    messages: {
        name: "This field is required."
    }
});
```

Form:

```
<?php   $form_att = array('id' => 'sample_form');
        echo form_open('Controller/function',$form_att); ?>
      <input type='text' name='name' id='name'/>
    <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Am i doing it right? The name field should not be empty.  Though its not working. Do i need to download another jquery plugin? i downloaded jquery. Though if this requires a specific jquery like how games have mods/expansions. Not entirely sure, but i wanted to do client-side validation .

EDIT:

After adding the validation jquery, the other functions wont work. If i take out the code snippet of the validation, the others work again.

I have buttons to append input types.

Sample,

```
$("#add").click(function(){
        $("#sample_td").append("<p><input type='text' id='sample[]' name='sample[]' size='60' placeholder='Instruction line'/></p>");
    });
```

If the button with id add is clicked it appends an input type inside the TD with id sample_td.

the [] in the id is to group all the appended input types so if i want to validate for sample to be required and there are varying number of how many was appended so it would be

rules: { sample[]: "Required" }, messages: { sample[]: "This field is required." }

so if any of the input types of sample will be validated. I got this idea from the same function as to adding [] to the name field so if i $_POST[sample']; it would return all the values of all the fields with name "sample[]" as an array.

Comment: yes download jquery validate plugin ,You surely having console errors in browser as you dont include validate plugin

Comment: Mind giving me a direct link? im quite confused on to how to fully utilize what jquery has to offer since whenever i go to their websites they offer loads of links and i haven o idea which one to DL. I thought clicking on download jquery would give me the whole package.

Comment: If you don't know [where to find the jQuery Validate plugin](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=jquery+validate+plugin), then where did you get the idea to use the `.validate()` method in the first place?

Comment: [StackOverflow also has a helpful tag wiki entry for this plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-validate/info).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Quote OP Comment:**

> *"I thought clicking on download jquery would give me the whole package."*

There is no "package".  jQuery is a JavaScript framework.  (It's a single JavaScript file and nothing else. It cannot possibly include every plugin on the planet.)  [Refer to jQuery API documentation to see the only methods that are provided](http://api.jquery.com/).

[jQuery Validate](http://jqueryvalidation.org) is a *third-party* jQuery **plugin**, not a method built into jQuery.  (There are likely [millions of third-party jQuery plugins](http://www.google.com/search?rls=en&q=jquery%20plugin).)

---

You must always include jQuery *first* and then include any third-party plugins next.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="your-path-to/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="your-path-to/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
```

Download or hot-link to jQuery Validate v1.11.1 from the CDN [here](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js).

You only need to use the minified OR the un-minified version of a plugin... not both.  Unless you're tinkering with the code or would like to read the code, just use the minified version.

---

And then only *after* you include jQuery and jQuery plugins, you'll include your own jQuery code.

Your code looks correct for the HTML markup you provided, but you should enclose it within a DOM ready event handler to make sure the HTML is ready before your function is fired.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {  // ensures HTML markup has been constructed

        $("#sample_form").validate({
            rules: {
                name: "required"
            },
            messages: {
                name: "This field is required."
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Question,  is there an option to validate on key up? not when i click submit, beucase im also doing server side validation. client side and server side, if i validate on submission of the form then it would be redundant as i could just validate on the controller then back to the view.

Comment: Please see i will edit my question. Something is wrong after adding the validation.

Comment: @user3432132, using this plugin, validation is on every `keyup`, by default.

Comment: @user3432132, your edit is a whole new question.  When you dynamically add input fields, _each_ must have a unique `name` attribute; and you must declare the rule _after_ it's created using the `.rules('add')` method, or by inline attribute.

Answer (score 1):

I found a nice jquery validation plugin here
http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

Or you can use html5 validation. `<input type='text' name='name' id='name' required/>`

Comment: Are there any requirements for HTML5? 

I use google chrome as my browser. Aslong as it supports HTML5 right?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_required
see this link.. there u can edit and check your codes..
chrome supports html5. To create html5 webpage, you have to declare doc type as <!DOCTYPE html>

Answer (score 0):

You need to load jQuery and jQuery Validation Plugin.

jQuery Validation Plugin is available at [jqueryvalidation.org](http://jqueryvalidation.org/)

Answer (score -1):

You can use an elegant solution for this if the question is always that the field is require or not require. This is working in the newest browsers.

http://www.the-art-of-web.com/html/html5-form-validation/

Comment: That's not an answer to the question.